# How do I uninstall visual studio 2013 that ha installed as an administrator?

Tags: windows-8.1, uninstall, visual-studio-2013

when I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 it stopped working and crashed.

I found out that I should installed it as an administrator. When I did that it installed perfectly.

However, when I run it it stopped working again and I cannot use it

I decided to uninstall this version of VS 2013 and get a new one.

I went to control panel to uninstall it but I could,t unistall it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your name is really hagar - wow. How about Onan or why not just go all the way and call yourself Balaam.   Or Satan!  I  suggest you  exorcise your computer.. Seriously though, just try to reinstall windows on there. And if it still fails, try another hard drive and see how that goes.  Or maybe if it's just VS that is crashing, then you just have something wrong with your VS installation.

Comment: Did you use the webplatform installer to install VS? if so, use it to uninstall it.